# Can't change Image source in my listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I'm working on an e-commerce application, i need to display a list of products -a product = one ImageView and some textViews- from the database, but when i extract the data from the database, everting works fine except the imageView, it shows the same image that is in the source Layout.

this is the getView() Method in my adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesproduits, null);
        holder.nomduProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomProduit);
        holder.prixDuProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prixProduit);
        holder.imageDuProduit = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageProduit);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+File.separator+lesProduits.get(position).getImage());
    Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
    System.out.println(path+File.separator+lesProduits.get(position).getImage());

    holder.imageDuProduit.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableImage);
    holder.nomduProduit.setText(lesProduits.get(position).getNomDuProduit());
    holder.prixDuProduit.setText(lesProduits.get(position).getPrixDuProduit());
    return convertView;
}
```

and below is the source Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageProduit"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nomProduit"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageProduit"
    android:text="Smart phone"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prixProduit"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nomProduit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nomProduit"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the background, not the foreground.
ImageView has both foregrond and background images.

instead of this

```
  holder.imageDuProduit.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableImage);
```

use this

```
 holder.imageDuProduit.setImageDrawable(drawableImage);
```